# flutter: how to group items by header and subheaders using GroupedListView

Tags: flutter, listview

I found a package that allows me to group/filter a list based on two criteria. However, it doesn't print the courses under the correct heading and also prints the entire list multiple times. Modifying group comparator and item comparator fields didn't help. Not sure how to fix

```
          body: GroupedListView<dynamic, String>(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          elements: _elements,
          groupBy: (element1) => element1['subjectName'],
          groupComparator: (value1, value2) => value2.compareTo(value1),
          //itemComparator: (item1, item2) =>
              //item1['subjectName'].compareTo(item2['subjectName']),
          order: GroupedListOrder.DESC,
          useStickyGroupSeparators: true,
          groupSeparatorBuilder: (String value) => Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
            child: Text(
              value,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ),
          
            itemBuilder: (c, element) {
              return GroupedListView<dynamic, String>(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  elements: _elements,
                  groupBy: (element) => element['courseName'],
                  groupComparator: (value1, value2) =>
                      value2.compareTo(value1),
                  itemComparator: (item1, item2) => item1['subjectName']
                  .compareTo(item2['subjectName']),
                  order: GroupedListOrder.DESC,
                  useStickyGroupSeparators: true,
                  groupSeparatorBuilder: (String value) => Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                        child: Text(
                          value,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                          //style: TextStyle(
                          //   fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      ),
                  itemBuilder: (c, element) {
                    return Container(
                        child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                      ListTile(
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 5.0),
                        // leading: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
                        title: Text(element['courseSection'],
                            textAlign: TextAlign.left),
                        //trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
                      ),
                      // ListTile(title: Text(element['courseSection'])),
                    ]));
});
})));
}`
```

Comment: Did you find solution on this? I have on hot restart or when setState() is called or build.. Some items from the list change places. For example in second Group first item switch place with some in the middle of the same group, if I hot restart they go back to order.. Weird..

Comment: @AlexApps - yes, the solution posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65986568/how-to-filter-list-dynamically-using-where-in-text-field-flutter/65999395#65999395 worked but I ended using listview.builder with stickyheader instead.